# Resetting an empty input field to 0 using a watcher

Tags: vuejs3

I have a circle of which degree of rotation is controlled by an input field.
Whenever the user erases the value of the input, the circle keeps the last digit as a degree of rotation.
So if for example, the user types in `30 degrees`, then erases the `30`, the circle stays rotated at `3 degrees` (the last digit of the input value).

I tried to set a watcher for the input field whereas if it becomes an empty string, the watcher sets the input to `0` but the `0` stays as demonstrated in the gif below the code.
Here's my code:

```html
<input type="number" v-model="degree" />
```

```js
data() {
    return {
      degree: 0,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    degree() {
      if (this.degree == "") {
        this.degree = 0;
      }
    },
  },
computed: {
    rotated() {
      return { transform: `rotate(${this.degree}deg)` };
    },
  },
```

[Illustration of the "bug"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3KUd.gif)

I want the `0` to disappear as soon as the user stats typing in a new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use `@keydown` on input to check if `degree` is `0` and change it to `""`. It will work for this case because `keydown` triggers before the value changing.

Note: vue will ignore the `value` changing, so watcher will not trigger. Also `event.which` check if the key presses is not backspace.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    degree: 0
  },
  watch: {
    degree(val) {
      if(val == ''){
        this.degree = 0;
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeZero(ev) {
      if(ev.which != 8 && ev.currentTarget.value == '0'){
        ev.currentTarget.value = '';
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#rotator {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <input type="number" @keydown="removeZero" v-model="degree" />
  
  <br />
  <div id="rotator" v-bind:style="{ transform: 'rotate('+ degree + 'deg)' }" >Hi!</div>
  
</div>
```

However, maybe you would like to consider another aproach like separate data you will manipulate from what you show to user. Example:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    inputDegree: 0
  },
  watch: {
    inputDegree(val) {
      this.inputDegree = parseInt(val) || 0;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    degree() {
      if(this.inputDegree == ''){
        return 0;
      }
      return parseInt(this.inputDegree) % 360;
    }
  },
});
```

```css
#rotator {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <input type="number" v-model="inputDegree" />
  
  <br />
  <div id="rotator" v-bind:style="{ transform: 'rotate('+ degree + 'deg)' }" >Hi!</div>
  
</div>
```

This way the user can input anything but you can always treat the value before using it to calculate something. And you will be free to change the way you show this value for the user (you can even put a mask like `999 deg` or something). Check that i'm using `%` to keep `degree` always between 0 and 360. It does not have affect here but it is just to show an advantage of separating what user see and change from what we manipulate and calculate.

Comment: I have trouble understanding how your second approach may solve the problem at hand, maybe it eludes me ( :

Comment: About your first suggestion, though, do you mean a method that would set the input (as in event.target.value) whenever there's a keydown in that input and that input has the sole value of 0? I think I like it if i understood it correctly

Comment: @dhiaagr i´ve updated with a snippet (stackoverflow only supports Vue2). I'll add a snippet for the second example too

Comment: Your first suggestion works smoothly, thank you ( : If you don't mind expanding on your second suggestion, as in what does the watcher exactly do?

Comment: Well, in the second suggestion, even with things "separated" we still have to format it to user. `parseInt('')` is equal to `NaN` that is falsy, so `parseInt('') || 0' will return '0'. Also `parseInt('0123')` is equal `123` so it will remove left side zeros.